# I always get memory warning when I use PHAsset in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory, phasset

I get a memory warning when I use my media gallery. It fetches all images/videos from my camera roll into the fetch result an you can slide through the content with a UIPageControl.
When I use "Instruments" it displays that: 
[image]

Here's some code

```
func showImage(obj: AnyObject!) {
    var image = UIImage()
    manager.requestImageForAsset(obj as! PHAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: photoOptions, resultHandler:
        {(result, info)->Void in
            image = result!
            self.imageView.image = image
            self.imageView.frame = self.contentView.bounds
            self.contentView.addSubview(self.imageView)
    })
}
```

and here I fetch the media to my PHFetch Result:

```
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

    PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions)
    PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: fetchOptions)

    let media = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(fetchOptions)
```

I have absolutely no idea what that means because I'm new in XCode and Swift. So what could be the reason?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should attach some code if you want to receive a helpful answer.

Comment: @mafioso Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have almost 1GB of CGImage allocations. You should try to reuse your cells or image views, release unused images. Also fetch image only when you are about to show it on the screen, don't fetch whole camera roll. If you are not working with fullscreen images, you should display thumbnails.